# Do Quests together with a Friend in WATCH_DOGS

Tags: watch-dogs, watch-dogs-bad-blood

It it possible to do Jobs together in Watch_Dogs?
So when I play with a buddy to take out a gang hideout or a gang convoi together?

Is this somehow possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes there are some ways to play coop.

Beside the coop in a mission you have the ability to play some quick mp games like hacking or racing.

I'm not sure if the coop support is everywhere integrated but on PC I've seen it so far. Not sure for Xbox/PS.

You'll need the Bad Blood DLC to play streetlights with your friend in coop.

The rest of the game will be just online hacking etc with some random opponents.

Hopefully this answers your question.

Comment: Sadly this answers my question

Comment: Yes it's not the best solution. The developers should have integrated the coop in the main game (even if it would be a patch after some months). To resell the multiplayer for some partials as a DLC isn't the best practice. Well... anyway. It's ubisoft. ;-)